# Anywhere Sliders With Add Condition Group

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.2

My desire is that for each different Category, a different slider will be displayed accordingly, so I tried using the 'Add Condition Group' feature in the Slider Manager (Nop version 4.2). Please see image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H98QV.png)

At the `CategoryTemplate.ProductsInGridOrLines.cshtml`, I tried this:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Widget", new { widgetZone = 
PublicWidgetZones.CategoryDetailBeforeBreadcrumb })
```

However, nothing happens when I select a category in the menu (`Model.CategoryBreadcrumb`) that is not present in the Condition Group, the slider still appears as usual.

So, what else do I need to do to make the slider only appear when I select a Category that is present in the Condition Group of the Anywhere Slider?

Thanks a lot.